# Wrong angle while drawing a partial circle with AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, drawing, angle

For a flash game project I am working on I want to create a camera which should be able to detect a player through ray-casting. The camera should be able to have different view angles (eg. 45 degrees or 90 degrees), and according to these view angles the ray-casting should vary. Creating the actual view angles using ray-casting doesn't cause a problem, however, for some reason that is beyond me the angles in which these view angles are positioned are wrong.

This is the code I use:

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < this._viewAngle; i++)
{
    var pointX:Number = (this._viewRange) * Math.cos(this._viewAngle + (i * Math.PI / 180));
    var pointY:Number = (this._viewRange) * Math.sin(this._viewAngle + (i * Math.PI / 180));
    this._rayHolder.graphics.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
    this._rayHolder.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
}
```

And this is the result:
(90 degrees)

[image: Camera 90 degrees]

(45 degrees)

[image: Camera 45 degrees]

I hope what I wrote was understandable enough, because I don't know how to explain it more clearlyIf anybody could shed some light on what I am doing wrong here, that would be awesome.

EDIT:
Changing `Math.cos(this._viewAngle + (i * Math.PI / 180));` to `Math.cos((this._viewAngle + i) * Math.PI / 180);` results in this:

(90 degrees)

[image: Camera 90 degrees]

(45 degrees)

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're not converting _viewAngle into radians.

Comment: Agreed. Also, maybe I don't understand it, but in reading your code I'm left w/the impression that `_viewAngle` is being used for two different things. 1) iterate over it to create the "field of view", 2)  but then you add it to the angle used in the sin/cos, as if it is also the angle that the camera is pointing.

Comment: @DavidMear I believe I do convert to radians using `* Math.PI / 180`. The other way around (`* 180 / Math.PI`) should produce degrees. I just named them wrong in my question.

Comment: @SunilD. Yes, I use the `_viewAngle` variable twice. I do this to draw a line for every radian / degree in the field of view.

Comment: @GabiBarrientos are you doing this: `Math.cos(this._viewAngle + (i * Math.PI / 180))` or this: `Math.cos( (this._viewAngle + i) * Math.PI / 180))`

Comment: @SunilD. As you can see I do the first of the two you mentioned. I will update my question with the result of testing the latter of the two.

Comment: The latest results are closer to what I would expect. You were converting `i` to radians but not `_viewAngle`. Now what I would also expect is that the camera angle and the "field of view" angles are two different variables. So that you add the camera's angle to `i` instead of "field of views" angle. Finally, you would also want half of the field of view to be on one side and half on the other, instead of all of it one side. Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @SunilD. I understand what you're getting at, but I use the camera.rotation property to angle the camera itself. The _viewAngle determines the width of the field of view. That being said, I don't quite understand why the angle of the field in reference to the camera itself is different in both tests, or how to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're close with your update. As Sunil D points out, you presumably just want to align the vision cone so that it's centred at 90˚ from the vertical. In other words, starting from `-_viewAngle * 0.5`:

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < this._viewAngle; i++)
{
    var pointX:Number = (this._viewRange) * Math.cos((-this._viewAngle * 0.5 + i) * Math.PI / 180);
    var pointY:Number = (this._viewRange) * Math.sin((-this._viewAngle * 0.5 + i) * Math.PI / 180);
    this._rayHolder.graphics.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
    this._rayHolder.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
}
```

*Edit:* While these equations work for this application, the following reflect Flash's odd coordinate systems more accurately. Specifically, with positive x to the right, positive y downwards:

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < this._viewAngle; i++)
{
    var pointX:Number = (this._viewRange) * Math.sin((90 - this._viewAngle * 0.5 + i) * Math.PI / 180);
    var pointY:Number = (this._viewRange) * -Math.cos((90 - this._viewAngle * 0.5 + i) * Math.PI / 180);
    graphics.lineTo(pointX + 100, pointY + 100);
    graphics.moveTo(100, 100);
}
```

Comment: Although I still don't quite understand why the 45˚ test would result in the field of view being centered to the left (relatively) of where it should be and the 90˚ test resulted in the field of view being centered to the right, this solution works perfectly. Thank you both David and Sunil.

Comment: You were *starting* the vision cone drawing from `_viewAngle` degrees, so if 0˚ points straight up, the 45˚ test *starts* from diagonally top-right, and the 90 test *starts* from directly to the right.